# Update input values into elements only JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created an index file so that the information entered here is added to the created element
this is for a review section
the `index.html` file is here, and includes the CSS and js

```js
    let name = document.querySelector('.name').value;
    let message = document.querySelector('.message').value;
    let btn = document.getElementById('button');
    let div = document.querySelector('.items')

    btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        let item = document.createElement('div')
        let inner = `
                <h3>${name}</h3>
                <p>${message}</p>
                `
        item.className = "message-item"        
        item.innerHTML = inner        
        div.append(item)
    });
```

```css
 html, body{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .msg{
            padding: 2em;
            margin: 2em;
            border-radius: 2vh;
            height: 70vh;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: left;
            flex-direction: column;
            background-color: #1e90ff;
        }
        .items{
            height: 65vh;
            overflow: scroll;
            color: white;
            width: 100%;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            margin: 10px;
        }
        input{
            padding: 10px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 8px;
            outline: none;
            font-size: 1em;
        }
        #button{
            padding: 10px 20px;
            border-radius: 8px;
            border: none;
            font-size: 1em;
        }
        .button{
            padding: 10px 20px;
            border-radius: 8px;
            border: none;
            font-size: 1em;
        }
        .message-item{
            background-color: black;
            padding: 1em;
            border-radius: 8px;
            margin: 3px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="msg">
        <div class="items"></div>
        <div class="input">
                <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Name">
                <input type="text" class="message" placeholder="Message">
                <button id="button">Submit</button>
                <button type="reset">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

So I am expecting it to append the elements which have different values
example once i enter the **name **"harry" and **message **as "this is the message"
and then i reset and enter another **name **and **message **then the newly created element should display the newly entered **name **and **message**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `name` variable should be a pointer to the element, not the value.

Also, you should clear the input after adding.

```js
const
  name = document.querySelector('.name'),
  message = document.querySelector('.message'),
  btn = document.getElementById('button'),
  div = document.querySelector('.items');

const handleAdd = (e) => {
  div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
    <div class="message-item">
      <h3>${name.value}</h3>
      <p>${message.value}</p>
    </div>
  `);
  name.value = '';    // Clear name
  message.value = ''; // Clear message
};

btn.addEventListener('click', handleAdd);
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.msg {
  padding: 2em;
  margin: 2em;
  border-radius: 2vh;
  height: 70vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: left;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #1e90ff;
}

.items {
  height: 65vh;
  overflow: scroll;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1em;
}

#button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.message-item {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="msg">
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="input">
    <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="text" class="message" placeholder="Message">
    <button id="button">Submit</button>
    <button type="reset">Reset</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

## A better approach

A better example would be to use a form. This way you can take advantage of built-in form validation, submission, and resetting.

For example, you can call elements by their name and you have the added bonus of <kbd>Enter</kbd> key support.

1. Enter a name
2. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd>
3. Enter a message
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   1. The item is added
   2. The form is cleared
   3. Focus is sent to the name

```js
const handleAdd = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevent page from navigating
  const
    form = e.target,
    formElements = form.elements,
    parent = form.closest('.msg'),
    items = parent.querySelector('.items');
  items.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
    <div class="message-item">
      <h3>${formElements.name.value}</h3>
      <p>${formElements.message.value}</p>
    </div>
  `);
  formElements.name.value = '';    // Clear name
  formElements.message.value = ''; // Clear message
  formElements.name.focus();
};

document.forms.namedItem('new-msg')
  .addEventListener('submit', handleAdd);
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.msg {
  padding: 2em;
  margin: 2em;
  border-radius: 2vh;
  height: 70vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: left;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #1e90ff;
}

.items {
  height: 65vh;
  overflow: scroll;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.form-btn {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.message-item {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="msg">
  <div class="items"></div>
  <form id="new-msg" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
    <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Message">
    <button type="submit" class="form-btn">Submit</button>
    <button type="reset" class="form-btn">Reset</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

---

### LocalStorage

Here is an example of local storage. The main idea here is how to store and restore the state of the messages.

```js
const MESSAGES_KEY = "messages";

const main = () => {
  // Restore all messages
  const messageContainer = document.querySelector(".items");
  __retrieveAllMessages().forEach((message) => {
    insertMessage(message, messageContainer);
  });
  // Add event listener
  document.forms.namedItem("new-msg").addEventListener("submit", handleAdd);
};

const saveMessage = (message) => {
  __saveAllMessages(__retrieveAllMessages().concat(message));
};

const insertMessage = (message, container) => {
  container.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", messageToHtml(message));
};

const messageToHtml = ({ name, message }) => `
  <div class="message-item">
    <h3>${name}</h3>
    <p>${message}</p>
  </div>
`;

const handleAdd = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevent page from navigating
  const form = e.target,
    message = {
      name: form.elements.name.value,
      message: form.elements.message.value,
    };
  saveMessage(message);
  insertMessage(message, form.closest(".msg").querySelector(".items"));
  form.elements.name.value = ""; // Clear name
  form.elements.message.value = ""; // Clear message
  form.elements.name.focus();
};

const __retrieveAllMessages = () => {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(MESSAGES_KEY) ?? "[]");
};

const __saveAllMessages = (messages = []) => {
  return localStorage.setItem(MESSAGES_KEY, JSON.stringify(messages));
};

main();
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Polywhirl and also can you tell me how can i save those elements from getting deleted by refresh or tab close

Comment: @BharathKesari you need to either store them in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), a database, or a file. I will include an example at the end, but it will not work in a snippet. You will need to run it in on web server, or in VSCode using the LiveServer extension.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the values of your input on every button submit button press, not just once on page load, and also you need to clear your inputs when you press the reset button

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('button');
let reset = document.getElementById('reset');
let div = document.querySelector('.items')

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let name = document.querySelector('.name').value;
  let message = document.querySelector('.message').value;
  let item = document.createElement('div')
  let inner = `
                <h3>${name}</h3>
                <p>${message}</p>
                `
  item.className = "message-item"
  item.innerHTML = inner;
  div.append(item)
});

reset.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let name = document.querySelector('.name').value = '';
  let message = document.querySelector('.message').value = '';
});
```

```css
html, body{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .msg{
            padding: 2em;
            margin: 2em;
            border-radius: 2vh;
            height: 70vh;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: left;
            flex-direction: column;
            background-color: #1e90ff;
            color: white;
        }
        .items{
            height: 65vh;
            overflow: scroll;
            color: white;
            width: 100%;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            margin: 10px;
        }
        input{
            padding: 10px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 8px;
            outline: none;
            font-size: 1em;
        }
        #button{
            padding: 10px 20px;
            border-radius: 8px;
            border: none;
            font-size: 1em;
        }
        .button{
            padding: 10px 20px;
            border-radius: 8px;
            border: none;
            font-size: 1em;
        }
        .message-item{
            background-color: black;
            padding: 1em;
            border-radius: 8px;
            margin: 3px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="msg">
        <div class="items"></div>
        <div class="input">
                <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Name">
                <input type="text" class="message" placeholder="Message">
                <button id="button">Submit</button>
                <button id="reset">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You get the values from your inputs before they are filled. They are just string values and do not update dynamically when the input changes.

I moved these lines to inside your function so that you get the most recent data every time you click the button.

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    let name = document.querySelector('.name').value;
    let message = document.querySelector('.message').value;
    let div = document.querySelector('.items')
    
    let item = document.createElement('div')
    let inner = `
            <h3>${name}</h3>
            <p>${message}</p>
            `
    item.className = "message-item"        
    item.innerHTML = inner        
    div.append(item)
});
```

```css
html, body{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .msg{
            padding: 2em;
            margin: 2em;
            border-radius: 2vh;
            height: 70vh;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: left;
            flex-direction: column;
            background-color: #1e90ff;
        }
        .items{
            height: 65vh;
            overflow: scroll;
            color: white;
            width: 100%;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            margin: 10px;
        }
        input{
            padding: 10px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 8px;
            outline: none;
            font-size: 1em;
        }
        #button{
            padding: 10px 20px;
            border-radius: 8px;
            border: none;
            font-size: 1em;
        }
        .button{
            padding: 10px 20px;
            border-radius: 8px;
            border: none;
            font-size: 1em;
        }
        .message-item{
            background-color: black;
            padding: 1em;
            border-radius: 8px;
            margin: 3px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="msg">
        <div class="items"></div>
        <div class="input">
                <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Name">
                <input type="text" class="message" placeholder="Message">
                <button id="button">Submit</button>
                <button type="reset">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```